# c++. "No match for operator"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ship
{
        string shipName;
        string shipYear;
    public:
        Ship(string n = "Titanic", string y = "1980")
        {
            shipName = n;
            shipYear = y;
        }
        void setShipName(string n) { shipName = n; }
        void setShipYear(string y) { shipYear = y; }
        string getShipName() const { return shipName; }
        string getShipYear() const { return shipYear; }
        virtual void print() const {}
};

class Cruiseship : public Ship
{
        int numPass;
    public:
        Cruiseship(int numPass) : Ship("Hawaii-ish", "1948")
        { this->numPass = numPass; }
        void setNumPass(int num) { numPass = num; }
        int getNumPass() const { return numPass; }
        void print() const
        { cout << this->getShipName() << this->getNumPass(); }
};

class CargoShip : public Ship
{
        int cargoCapacity;
    public:
        CargoShip(int cargoCapacity) : Ship("USBEB", "2050")
        { this->cargoCapacity = cargoCapacity; }
        void setCargoCapacity(int cc) { cargoCapacity = cc; }
        int getCargoCapacity() const { return cargoCapacity; }
        void print() const
        { cout << this->getShipName() << this->getCargoCapacity(); }
};

int main()
{
    const int NUM_SHIPS = 3;
    Ship *ships[NUM_SHIPS] =
        {
            new Ship,
            new Cruiseship(2000),
            new CargoShip(900)
        };
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        cout << ships[i]->print();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        delete ships[i];
}
```

directions:

> Design a Ship class that has the following members:
>   --A member variable for the name of the ship (a string)
>   --A member variable for the year that the ship was built (a string)
>   --A constructor and appropriate accessors and mutators
>   --A virtual print function that displays the ship's name and the year it was built.
>
> Design a CruiseShip class that is derived from the Ship class.
>   The CruiseShip class should have the following members:
>   --A member variable for the maximum number of passengers (an int)
>   --A constructor and appropriate accessors and mutators
>   --A print function that overrides the print function in the base class. The CruiseShip class's print function should display only the ship's name and the maximum number of passengers.
>
> Design a CargoShip class that is derived from the Ship class.
>   The CargoShip class should have the following members:
>   --A member variable for the cargo capacity in tonnage (an int).
>   --A constructor and appropriate accessors and mutators.
>   --A print function that overrides the print function in the base class.  The CargoShip class's print function should display only the ship's name and the ship's cargo capacity.
>
> Demonstrate the classes in a program that has an array of Ship pointers. The array elements should be initialized with the addresses of dynamically allocated Ship, CruiseShip, and CargoShip objects.

This is what i have so far. Im getting errors:(

Comment: What errors, and where? How do you compile it?

Comment: @Deduplicator  in the main
 cout << ships[i]->print();

Comment: `cout << ships[i]->print()` I'm sure you can figure out what's wrong with this yourself. Look at the declaration and body of `print`...

Comment: @Radiodef i was not able to spot anything. you want me to take a look at print method?

Comment: Yes ... look at the return type. Look at what `print` does.

Comment: @Radiodef print is not doing anything.

Comment: @Radiodef also return type is void

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    cout << ships[i]->print();
```

to:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    ships[i]->print();
```

You need to understand your compiler error.. Which compiler are you using? Can you post its error message?

My compiler states:

> main.cpp: In function int main(): main.cpp:56:14: error: no
>   match for operator<< (operand types are std::ostream {aka
>   std::basic_ostream} and void)
>            cout << ships[i]->print();

This means that `cout` is waiting for a stream of `char` but it is getting `void`.. quick look to your `print` and you catch the problem. Hope it helps!